# Connect to multiple remote machines to run automation scripts

Tags: remote-access, coded-ui-tests

I am an automation engineer where I need to run 450 CodedUI scripts on multiple machines. I have 15 machines on which I run these scripts. 
To resolve my trouble I am using Microsoft's tool Remote Desktop Connection Manager to login to these machines. But I am getting the error on failed scripts that "Either the window is locked or minimized", but when I used to directly login to these machines and run the scripts there were no such issues.
I am unable to find any resolution. I tried one more tool to connect to 15 machines , i.e. AppVision tool as well. Even with that tool I am facing the errors on all my scripts that Some control is blocking the control to be clicked in.
I need to know if I can have any other tool or way where I would be able to login to the machines in one go and run automation scripts without any errors.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: How are the various computers being used to run the tests? Which have Visual Studio installed and which have test agent software? How are the tests started on the remote machines?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI requires that the screen saver is disabled on the remote machines.

Coded UI interacts with the desktop of the machine running the tests. When the screen saver is active it controls the desktop and, effectively, prevents Coded UI from interacting with the application under test.

The question refers to "Microsoft's tool Remote Desktop Connection Manager" so perhaps you are not using test agent software to run the test. Check this [Microsoft web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx) and [this Microsoft forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51d56201-506f-41e2-90e5-e2cbe718f5a7/running-coded-ui-test-without-vs-2010-test-agent-and-test-controller?forum=vsautotest) for more details on how to set up remote computers to run Coded UI.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But these settings are already done on the machines before I ran the tests. So, if you could suggest any other option on this problem that would be of great help ?